# elements width not changing in webkit browsers when resizing the screen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I got a problem with responsible design. I have menu buttons floating next to eachother, each button contains icon and text. Text is on the right from icon... On smaller window/resolution text goes under the icon so button is not that wide. When I extend window from smaller to wider I expect text to go back from underneath to right but it doesnt. This problem appears in chrome/safari. In firefox goes everything well. Anyone experienced this problem? Any ideas?

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6pmzJ/2/) try resizing your screen...

```
.menu ul li a { display: block; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 15px 20px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 30px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6pmzJ/5/

Fixed in the above fiddle:

1) You weren't closing your IMG tags.

2) The issue appears to be browser related. I added span around the text and added the following CSS:

```
.menu ul li span { float: left; display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Many thanks man. According to W3C "In HTML the <img> tag has no end tag." so I wasnt closing it

Comment: Well the non-closure didn't break it, but it did at least fix the formatting in JSFiddle :).